# Equivalent definition for an open interval around a point in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, interval-arithmetic

Let $I$ be an open interval containing $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I know that $I=(\inf(I),\sup(I))$.

Is it possible to find $\delta>0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)=I?$

This would imply that $\sup(I)-\delta=a$ and $\inf(I)+\delta=a$. Then we get $\delta=[\sup(I)-\inf(I)]/2$. But picking $\delta:=[\sup(I)-\inf(I)]/2$ does necessarily imply that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)=I$, since this would imply that $a=\frac{\inf(I)+\sup(I)}{2}$ which may not necessarily be the case.

I guess this shows that $I\ne(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ generally. Maybe it's possible to embed $I$ in an interval of the form $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ or the other way around?

Comment: No. Consider $(0,3)$ and $a=1$.

Comment: @DonThousand But can we always find $\delta>0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset I$? In your example we can take $(1/2,3/2)\subset(0,3)$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: That's a different question and "yes."  Measure the distance from $a$ to both ends, take the smaller measure, and halve it.

Comment: True. Redacted.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ I\subset\mathbb{R}\ $ is an interval, then $\ I = (\inf (I), \sup (I))\ = (a-\delta, a+\delta),\ $ where

$a=\frac{\inf (I) + \sup (I)}{2}\ $ and $\ \delta = \ \frac{\sup (I) - \inf (I)}{2}.$

You can confirm via calculation that $\ a-\delta = \inf(I)\ $ and that $\ a+\delta = \sup(I).$